# Terminal Server logon script

Tags: batch-file, netstat

I'm writing a simple .bat script to track logons to our terminal servers and append the records to a single CSV file. I can't quite get my script to behave correctly. Almost everything is working, but the **clientip** variable has an entire line of output instead of just the IP address that I desire. I don't think I'm doing the TOKENS correctly, and I suspect it's because the output of the netstat command isn't delimited by a tab character.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('TIME/T') DO SET TIME=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=3 delims=<tab>" %%B IN ('netstat -n ^| find ":3389" ^| find "ESTABLISHED"') DO SET CLIENTIP=%%B
echo Logon,%username%,%date%,%time%,%computername%,%clientip% >> \\dc01\c$\logons.csv
```

If an example output of `netstat -n | find ":3389" | find "ESTABLISHED"` is

`TCP    10.10.20.100:3389      68.46.xxx.xxx:50373     ESTABLISHED`

then how can I set the **clientip** variable to only (last digits redacted, of course) 68.46.xxx.xxx? A bonus would be leaving off the port, in this case ":50373".

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, more a suggestion: drop this batch stuff and write something based on windows scripting host. It is more maintainable and understandable than all this tokens parsing fuss.

Comment: Use a space as the delimiter.

Comment: Use `tokens=4 delims=: ` (last char. is a space), then you'll get `68.46.xxx.xxx` only; if it doesn't work, add TAB to `delims`, *before* the space...

Comment: Is that always 5 digits after the colon (`68.46.xxx.xxx:50373`)?    `%clientip:0,-6%`. If not, use another `for /f "delims=:" %%i in ("%clientip%") do set clientip=%%i`

Comment: I would be surprised if there was not already log information maintained in the OS administrative logs. Perhaps it would be better to extract the information from there rather than trying to manually capture it. There is probably a Powershell way to access the administrative logs.

Comment: Ahh I had just thought of something - this entire approach will not work in my environment because the netstat command will return all RDP connections. For a terminal server with multiple remote users, it's impossible to match up the remote IP with the user. I may have to explore the suggestion @Marged provided.

Comment: Perhaps the query sessions command is what you need, give it a try: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/186592